# keeping of all javascript functions in one place

Tags: php, javascript

In php website I am using different javascript functions in different pages for example page a calls functions 1,2,3  and page b calls functions 2, 4, 6 and page c calls functions 3, 6 
can I place all javascript functions in one file

Comment: yes. you will get advantage of reduced http hits to server. in your case if you have proper expiration and cache headers for your javascript file, you can reduce 60% traffic for that resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In HTML you can include an external Javascript file like this:

```
<script src="js/six_util_functions.js"></script>
```

So as long as your PHP outputs that in the right place, you should have no trouble calling functions 1-6 from anywhere in your HTML pages.